# JOOMLA: How to create a simple image uploader for custom component

Tags: php, file-upload, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'm developing a custom Joomla component for creating, editing and saving data of single records including images. I know that in **admin/models/forms/record.xml** there must be field `name="image" type="file" accept="image/*"` but how and where do I need to write the simple php-code for uploading images to specific folder, in which file and how?

Comment: Did you look in the manual for files handling: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Thanks, but I need the codes from API Joomla for example https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_filesystem_package (see example) but I don't know where do I need to write it

Comment: You can make a component using http://www.component-creator.com that uses either the field "file" or "media".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. if we use field type '[media](https://docs.joomla.org/Media_form_field_type)' in record.xml there is no need to
   write upload code.
2. if we use field type 'file' then we can write upload code in model (models/record.php) . we will put upload code in save function after overriding it.

save function will look like

```
public function save($data)
{
  //file upload code.
  return parent::save($data);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that we need to put upload code in **models** /record.php, not in **controllers** /record.php ? In my model there is no save function - only loadFormData(), getForm() and getTable() and if I add save() function with upload code I get the error **Save failed with the following error: MycomTableMycom::bind(*NULL*)**

Comment: @stckvrw we can write upload code in controller as well. but respecting rule. 'thin controller & fat model' i suggested model. if your model is child of JModelAdmin their is no need of function getTable. MycomTableMycom::bind(NULL) mens your table class is getting nothing to be saved.